# How to define the optimal lag K in GARCH-MIDAS?

Tags: finance

Does anyone here have experience with GARCH-MIDAS? I estimated a garch midas model using the package mfGARCH and I have to choose the lag K that corresponds to the model with the minimum BIC.

**The problem is** that I Don't know where to stop since the BIC continues to decrease each time I increase the Lag K ( this was the case until i reached K=70 which I find unrealistic ! ).

Is that common ? Or, is there any additional condition to fix the lag K  (the significance of some parameters in the output, for instance...).

Comment: Questions like this are better suited for the Cross Validated suite.

Comment: You mean out-of-sample testing ? I'll do that but after deciding on the in-sample garch-midas models (for which I'm stuck on the optimal lag determination).

Comment: Actually Cross Validated is the name of the Stack Exchange site for statistics. It's worth checking out if you have questions like this often.